# Finding the limit of a sequence of random variables in the Wasserstein metric.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

For this problem, consider the $L^2(\Omega)$ space of random vectors. Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables with $X_n \sim \mu_n$. We say that $(\mu_n)$ converges (in the Wasserstein sense) to $\mu$, the probability distribution of some $X\in L^2(\Omega)$, if, and only if:

1. $E[X_{n}^2]\to E[X^2]$ as $n \to \infty$;
2. $\mu_n \implies \mu$, as $n \to \infty$ ($\implies$ is the convergence in distribution).

For simplicity, let's say that $X_n$ converges to $X$.

Define:
$$X_n = \sum_{j=1}^n W_j U_{j,n}Z_j, \quad n \in \mathbb N,$$
where:

- $(W_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a fixed realization of a stationary and ergodic sequence in the following sense:
  \begin{equation}\label{erg}\tag{E}
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n f(W_{j}) \,\overset{a.s}{\longrightarrow}\, E[f(W_1)],\quad (n \to \infty)
  \end{equation}
  Moreover, suppose $E[W_j]=0$, for all $j$.
- $(U_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb N}\overset{iid}{\sim}Bernoulli(\lambda/n)$, for each $n =1,2,\cdots$. Moreover $(Z_{j})_{j\in \mathbb N}\sim IID(0,\sigma^2)$, i.e., an iid sequence with zero mean and $E[Z_j^2]= \sigma^2< \infty$. Finally, $(U_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ and $(Z_{j})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ are independent.

First, notice that $(U_{j,n}Z_j)_{j}$ are iid. Moreover, using $f(w)=w^2$ in (\ref{erg}), we have:
\begin{equation}\label{I}\tag{I}
E[X^2]= E[ Z_1^2U_{1,n}^2] \sum_{j=1}^n W_{j}^2 = \sigma^2 \lambda \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n W_{j}^2 \,\overset{a.s}{\longrightarrow}\, \sigma^2 \lambda \, E[W_1^2],\quad (n \to \infty) 
\end{equation}
Notice that if $Z_j=1$ for all $j$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi_{X_n}(t) &=  \varphi_{\sum_{j=1}^n W_j U_{j,n}}(t) =\prod_{j=1}^n \varphi_{U_n}(W_jt) = \prod_{j=1}^n E\left[ e^{i t W_j U_n}  \right] \\
&= \prod_{j=1}^n \left(e^{i t W_j}P[U_n=1] + P[U_n=0]\right)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n \left(e^{i t W_j}\frac{\lambda}{n} + 1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right) \\
&= \prod_{j=1}^n \left(1+ \frac{\lambda}{n} \left[e^{i t W_j} - 1\right]\right) 
\end{aligned}
$$
Taking $\log$ and using $\log(1+x)\approx x$ (for $x$ approx zero) we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log \varphi_{X_n}(t) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \log \left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n} \left[e^{i t W_j} - 1\right]\right) \approx\frac{\lambda}{n}  \sum_{j=1}^n \left[e^{i t W_j} - 1\right]\,\overset{a.s}{\longrightarrow}\, \lambda E[e^{itW_1}-1]
\end{aligned}
$$
The convergence is by doing $f(w)= e^{itw}-1$, for any $t$, in (\ref{erg}). Thus:
\begin{equation}\label{II}\tag{II}
\varphi_{X_n}(t) \to_{a.s} e^{\left\{\lambda \left(E[e^{itW_1}] - 1\right)\right\}} = e^{\left\{\lambda \left(\varphi_{W_1}(t) - 1\right)\right\}}
\end{equation}
This means that if $Z_j=1$, by (\ref{I}) and (\ref{II}), we have $(X_n)$ converges to $X=\sum_{j=1}^N W_{j,1}$, where $N \sim Poisson (\lambda)$. Remember that $X$ has a [Compound Poison Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution). Here, $(W_{j,1})_{j \in \mathbb N}$ are iid copies of $W_1$ and are independent of $N \sim Poisson (\lambda)$.

**Question**

I want to try to figure out where does $(X_n)$ converge in the general case $(Z_{j})_{j\in \mathbb N}\sim IID(0,\sigma^2)$. Notice that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi_{X_n}(t) &=  \varphi_{\sum_{j=1}^n W_j U_{j,n} Z_j }(t) =\prod_{j=1}^n \varphi_{U_n Z_j}(W_jt) = \prod_{j=1}^n E\left[ e^{i t W_j U_n Z_j}  \right]  
\end{aligned}
$$
But I can't find a way to deal with the variable $Z_j$. According to (\ref{I}), I would bet that $X_n$ converges to $X = \sum_{j=1}^N W_{j,1}$, where $N \sim Poisson(\lambda \sigma^2)$ or even for $X = \sigma^2\sum_{j =1}^N W_{j,1}$, $N \sim Poisson(\lambda)$.

Some help?

*Update*

I don't know if it can help anything or is necessary, but we can assume that $Z_j\sim t_\nu$, a t-student distribution with $\nu>2$. But I would also like to know what happens, for example, if $Z_j \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Eh, the product of $W_j$ and $Z_j$ need not be ergodic (see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161875/multiplication-of-two-ergodic-and-stationary-processes), so I am unsure what you can get. I would suggest  not making the bet you are proposing making.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Perhaps it is not necessary for the product to be ergodic. My initial idea was to try to find a closed formula for $\varphi_{U_nZ_1}(tW_j)$. See for example (\ref{I}), it was not necessary to use ergodicity of $W_j Z_j$. Actually, I'm interested in $Z_j$ being $N(0, \sigma^2)$ or $Z_j\sim t_\nu$, a t-student distribution.