# Compute the characteristic function of the product of a Bernoulli and a continuous distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This topic has to do with a slightly more complex question, but that can be solved by solving the following problem. That's why I decided to open a new, less contaminated question:

Let $\lambda>0$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. Consider

- $U_n \sim \hbox{Bernoilli}(\lambda/n)$;
- $Z\sim F$, with $E[Z]=0$ and $\sigma^2:= E[Z^2]< \infty$;
- $U_n$ and $Z$ independent.

**Question**

Given some $w \in \mathbb R$, Is there any closed formula for the characteristic function of the product $U_n Z$?

$$\varphi_{U_nZ}(t w)= \mathbb E \left[ e^{i tw U_n Z } \right] $$
More specifically, I'm looking for a formula involving $\sigma^2= E[Z^2]$.
Is this possible?

Actually, I am interested in the case of $Z \sim t_\nu$, a t-student distribution with $\nu>2$ being the degrees of freedom parameter. Note that in this case, we have $\sigma^2 = \frac{\nu}{\nu- 2}$. However, I would also like to analyze the case $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. For this reason, I generalized it as $Z \sim F$.

By way of information, the most complex question I said at the beginning of the post is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721921/finding-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-random-variables-in-the-wasserstein-metric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess $\lambda/n<1$ otherwise the distribution of $U_n$ is not well defined. Since $U_n$ and $Z$ are independent, we get
$$E[e^{i\xi U_nZ}]=E[E[e^{i\xi U_nZ}|U_n]]=\frac{\lambda}{n}E[e^{i\xi Z}]+\frac{n-\lambda}{n}$$
e.g. in case $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ we get $E[e^{i\xi U_nZ}]=\frac{\lambda}{n}e^{i\xi \mu-\xi^2\sigma^2/2}+\frac{n-\lambda}{n}$.